# C# - function skip "if" loop

Tags: c#

```
static void PrintPartOfArray(int[] array, int from, int to)
    {
        int x = array.Length;

       if (from > x && from < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("there is an exeption!");

        }
        if (to > x && to < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("there is an exeption!");
        }
        else
        {



            for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array2 = new int[] { 3, 6, 54, 24, -90, 7, 4 };
        PrintPartOfArray(array2,2,7);

    }
```

it supposes to show the "exception error when the function receives a number outside the length of the array, for some reason it not working, when I checked with the debugger it simply skipped the if loops, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the structure follow if, else if, else. Not if, if, else? I'm not sure I understand the question to be honest. Which if is being skipped?

Comment: When you debug, what are the runtime values of your variables?  Which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?  For example, wouldn't `array.Length` *always* be a non-negative value.  What possible value of `from` would ever satisfy that first condition?

Comment: If `from > x`then it can't possibly also be less than 0 - you can't possibly have an array with a negative length.

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work, the thing is even with the first IF loop when I use the debugger it doesn't even check the terms of the loop...

Comment: @maorpeer: (1) `If` is not a *loop*.  (2) It *does* check the terms, and they evaluate to `false`.  So it skips the body of the `if` block.  That's exactly how `if` blocks work.

Comment: I Know it cant have an array with a negative number that the idea, it suppose to show an error if the function receive a number out of the length of the array.

Comment: There's lots of problems with your conditions and the way you're writing your `if` statements.  For example, `from > x` and `from < 0` should never happen at the same time.

Comment: yea sorry I wrote loop by accident, and the thing is it not checking the terms, the idea here is I put a number in the main that I know is outside of the array so the "if" will catch that and print the write.line error, but form some reason it just skips it and prints the function anyway.

Comment: Do you also need to check `from <= to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider "early return" for things like this.

```
if (from > array.Length - 1 || to > array.Length - 1 || from < 0 || to < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("One of your arguments is out of range.");
    return;
}

// Normal, error-free code goes here.
```

Comment: Or even better, instead of printing that there is an exception, actually throw an exception!

Comment: Well, yes.  But that would happen anyway, even without the range checking.

Comment: Stylistically, you can argue about whether it's better to do an early return or an `else` statement in cases like this. (Some people are quite dogmatic about that point, I'm not though).

Comment: The logic is much easier to follow on an early return.  One Entry, One Exit goes all the way back to the C days, when memory had to be deallocated before you exited from the function (not a problem in c#).

Comment: Early exit can also mean objects get GC'd sooner.

Comment: @DavidG An `else` statement would have the same effect in this case. Also, nit-picky point: it would make them *eligible* for garbage collection sooner. Technically, that doesn't mean that they actually will be garbage collected sooner because you can't know "in advance" exactly when the garbage collector will run.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica That's why I said *can also mean*. Also an early exit usually means you can write code with fewer levels of nesting - i.e. drop the `else` completely.

Comment: @DavidG Fair enough. You can make an argument either way in this case I think though, there's no definitive right or wrong answer.

Comment: @maorpeer You want the -1 since you iterate all the way to the value of `to` you'd want it to be less than the last index which is `Length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

If `from` and `to` are greater than `x`, they can't possibly also be less than 0. Recall that `x` is the length of an array, which can't be negative. That being said, it's literally impossible for either of your `if` statements to evaluate to `true`. Did you mean `||` instead?

Also, the last index of the array is `array.Length - 1`, *not* `array.Length`. Similarly, the first item in the array is at index `0`, *not* index `1`. I think that your array indices are off by 1 here.

Comment: this the assignment I got: I needed to create a function that receive an array and two int numbers "from" and "to", the function need to print all the numbers in the array from and to the numbers entered, if a number was entered that it outside the length of the array it should print an error, the first part works fine, and I put the "if" to check for numbers outside of the array, I entered a number outside of the array in the main program on purpose fo check it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @maorpeer I think you want to do `||` instead of `&&` in your `if` statements. `&&` means that both of the statements have to be true for the `if` statement to "run", which is impossible in this case. `||` means that at least one of them has to be true.